# Making a list of object in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a bit rusty on C++, haven't used it for a while. So I need to make a data structure that can hold objects and do operations with them. Just like a array list. Now I first create and init a dynamic array of my class type :

```
Student* array_of_students = new Student[SIZE];
```

Then I create a Student object, say like this :

```
Student student(param1, param2, etc..);
```

I also provide a destructor since I use a lot of char pointers (I know I should use string but this is  for learning purpose only.) where I delete number of pointers that hold some names.

```
~Student(){ /* delete filed1; etc */ }
```

Well, when I try to list those names, I get some random values, probably because pointers are deleted, meaning destructor is called, and even if I have reference to a particular object with `array_of_students`, those fields are destroyed and I don't have anything to display. This probably happens because `Student` instance goes out of scope and calls it's destructor.

So what is the solution in here? How can I hold them as long as `array_of_students` is alive?

I believe I need to define some sort of copy constructor that will copy that original student instance to a new copy
that will be referenced by `array_of_students`. Your thoughts would be helpful.

EDIT :

```
class Student{

private :
   char *_name;

   public :

   Student(){}
   Student(char* name){

      _name = new char[strlen(name)];
      strcpy(_name, name); }

   char* getNaziv(){return _name;}
   ~Student(){delete _name;}

};

int main()
{
    Student* array_of_students = new Student[5];
    char input[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << "Input name : "<<endl;
        cin >> input;
        Student tmp(input);
        array_of_students[i] = tmp;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        cout <<"Name is : "<< array_of_students[i].getNaziv()<< endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The C++ equivalent to (Java's) array list is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Please refrain from using raw arrays :)

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE.

Comment: Like I said, am not allowed to use vectors. Only raw.

Comment: @nhrnjic6 Who disallows that? God? Your mom? Without reasoning, I'd just close that as offtopic.

Comment: Maybe at least use smart pointers to manage those raw arrays?

Comment: You don't have to use `new` to create an object either. `Student array_of_students[SIZE];` works just fine. Please don't write Java in C++, it is not going to work.

Comment: SIZE is all upper case so it should be a constant. Since it should be a constant, there is no need to dynamically allocate the array. `Student array_of_students[SIZE];` should be sufficient.

Comment: And Bo Persson types just a bit faster than I.

Comment: You're mixing incompatible ideas and doing too many "bad practice" things that we really can't follow what you're actually asking about in this question.  Post some code that demonstrates an issue, or use your debugger, please. Also, everyone is convinced you are asking us to do your homework because of the "not allowed to use vector" comment. Writing your own code to do what std::vector does, then complaining about bugs, is just ... no.

Comment: src code is in edit. I know its bad, but my school requires it like that

Comment: You forgot about the null terminator… And your school should probably turn it into a ___C___ course.

Comment: this works when I delete destructor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: @nhrnjic6 Walk through it in a debugger. Without the destructor, you leak the memory `_name` is pointing to. Who (which object) owns the memory pointed to by the `_name` member?

Comment: If you place output statements in places like the destructor (and possibly the constructor, although that's pretty obvious), it becomes clearer where these are called. If that's not where you want, you can change things in your loop until you have something that works.

Comment: Currently you create the object `tmp`. Then you copy `tmp` to the array. This operation just copy the pointer to the array. Then `tmp` is destroyed. Since the destructor destroyes the string, the pointer in the array is inavlid. You have to copy or move the string in this situation. std::string or std::shared_ptr would not cause this problems. Alternative you could use a assignment operator for your class. You may also want a copy constructor. Maybe you could also use a move operator.

Comment: If your school requires it to be like THAT, your teacher should resign immediately (unless it's some kind of cruel punishment). Unfortunately, it is all too common for teachers to enforce awful programming practices. By all means, code how you have to for class (heck, implement your own linked list if you may), but please, PLEASE make sure you *know* the correct approaches for any future programming you do. Yours, the C++ community, and anyone who has had to maintain/refactor codebases written by people like your teacher.

Comment: You are missing the point, but thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use char arrays to store string, use instead `std::string`. And if it is possible, don't use `new` keyword to allocate memory, let C++ take care of allocation and deallocation of memory for you.

And don't use raw arrays of `Students`, it's preferred to use `std::vector` or other container classes. Like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Student
{
        private :
                std::string _name;

        public :
                Student ( );
                Student ( std::string& name );

                void name ( std::string& );
                std::string& name ( );
};

Student::Student ( )
{
        /* Constructor with no parameters, do some crazy stuff... */
}

Student::Student ( std::string& name )
{
        this -> name ( name );
}

void Student::name ( std::string& name )
{
        this -> _name = name;
}

std::string& Student::name ( )
{
        return ( this -> _name );
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
        std::vector<Student> array_of_students;
        std::string input;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Input name : " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> input;

            Student tmp ( input );
            array_of_students.push_back ( tmp );
        }

        for( auto sit = array_of_students.begin ( ); sit != array_of_students.end ( ); ++ sit )
        {
                std::cout <<"Name is : "<< ( *sit ).name ( ) << std::endl;
        }

        return ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Output:

```
Input name :
Name_01
Input name : 
Name_02
Input name : 
Name_03
Input name : 
Name_04
Input name : 
Name_05
Name is : Name_01
Name is : Name_02
Name is : Name_03
Name is : Name_04
Name is : Name_05
```